# DropZone inside form returning status 302

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-routing, dropzone.js

I'm using Laravel + DropZone to create a `multiple-upload-drag-&-drop-zone`

MyjQuery call

```
if($().dropzone) {
    var lstDropZone = jQuery('.dropzone');
    lstDropZone.each(function () {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        if(!$this.attr('id')) { $this.attr('id', 'dzRand_' + jQuery.guid++); }
        var name = !$this.data('name') ? 'arquivo_upload' : $this.data('name');
        var size = !$this.data('size') ? 10 : parseInt($this.data('size'));
        var url = $this.data('url');

        $this.dropzone({
            paramName: name, // The name that will be used to transfer the file
            maxFilesize: size, // MB
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            url: url,
            parralelUploads: 100,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            init: function() {

                var submitButton = document.querySelector(".btn-submit");
                var myDropzone = this; // closure

                submitButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    console.log("the button is clicked");
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    myDropzone.processQueue();
                    console.log("after processQueue");
                });

                this.on("complete", function (file) {
                    console.log("Added file.");
                });
                this.on("sendingmultiple", function () {
                    console.log("sending multiple");
                });
                this.on("successmultiple", function (files, response) {
                    console.log("success multiple");
                });
                this.on("errormultiple", function (files, response) {
                    console.log("error multiple");
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

My routes.php

```
Route::post('news-img-upload', ['as' => 'news-img-upload', 'uses' => 'NewsImageController@upload']);
```

My blade.php

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => route('news-img.store'), 'role' => 'form', 'class' => 'item-form', 'files' => true, 'id' => 'myForm']) }}

    {{-- Here goes more fields that will be posted together --}}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label(null, trans('admin.Arquivo'), ['class' => 'control-label required']) }}
        <div class="form-controls clearfix">
            <div class="dropzone dz-clickable" data-url="{{URL::route('news-img-upload')}}" data-name="arquivo_upload">
                <div class="dz-default dz-message" data-dz-message="">
                    <span>My upload field</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-action">
        {{ Form::submit(Save, ['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-submit']) }}
    </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

The console (vide-code) show the info like it would have access the controller

[image: Console]

But in the Network tab, it shows only **status 302** without any return

My controller

```
public function upload(){
    return 'Something isnt fishy';
    print_r(Input::all());
    print_r(Input::file());
    die(' - uploads');
}
```

This is the first time I'm using DropZone, so I don't know what I should aim here for.

PS: I need it to **NOT** be an form, but a div instead. So I used the info of search and also [documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically) to do that.

---

Note (off-topic, but...): I changed the `dropzones = document.querySelectorAll(".dropzone");` to `dropzones = document.querySelectorAll(".dropzone-auto");` on line 1427 instead of using `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;` so I could have a `autoDiscover` in forms. (this method is meant to be generic)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using dropzone and MVC and the problem was on the server limitation to upload files. In my case I had to change the limitation on the web.config of my project, you have to do the same on your laravel project.